# How display scroll-bar for UITextView always?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview

`UITextView` seems to display scroll bars just under the following conditions:-
1. The contents of view is more than View can display
2. User scrolls the `UITextView`

Is this right? Is there any smart way to display scroll-bar anytime?

Comment: you should check mark, if the answer is accepted.

Comment: @VaibhavSaran, I can't say that your solution is displaying scroll indicator always as it was asked, but it is really good and useful answer.

Answer (score 19):

```
[textView flashScrollIndicators];
```

---

> `UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`.
>   So there is a method
>   `flashScrollIndicators` that you can
>   call to prompts the user that the view
>   is scrollable.  It only flashes once
>   for few seconds where user comes to a
>   page that contains `UIScrollView` or its
>   subclass.  You may set timer to call
>   this method more than one time.

Comment: How does this answer the question?